# VBA: Avoid highlighing of text

Tags: vba, ms-access

i have a textfield in MS Access form. When i click in this field, the symbol at the position where i clicked is highlighted. I just want the cursor at this position.

How can i achieve this?

thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox.selstart ?

Comment: If you mean "manually", press Ctrl+Shift+F8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have an Input Mask defined.  If you don't want this behavior, you need to remove the Input Mask.

Comment: ah yes.. it is a datefield with a format to show/enter YYYY only. I cannot change this, because there some queries depending :(